# With $f(x)= 32 \cosh(x) \sinh(2x) $, determine the slope of its tangent at $( \ln 2 , \, 75)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

With $f(x)= 32 \cosh(x) \sinh(2x)$, determine the slope of its tangent at $( \ln 2 ,\, 75)$.

**My work**

$$\sinh x \cosh y = \frac{1}{2}(\sinh (x + y) + \sinh (x - y))$$

$$\cosh(x) \sinh(2x)= \frac{1}{2}(\sinh (x + 2x) + \sinh (x - 2x)).$$

Then,

$$\cosh(x) \sinh(2x)= \frac{1}{2}(\sinh (3x) + \sinh (-x))$$

$$f'(x)= 16 '[(\sinh (3x) + \sinh (-x))]=16[3\cosh(3x) -\cosh(x)].$$

Is that correct, or I have made any arithmetic errors?

Comment: Please use LaTeX formatting.

Comment: @user155971 I have LaTeX'd your post but please learn how to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The expression for $\cosh(x)\sinh(2x)$ is not quite right. It should be $\frac{1}{2}(\sinh(3x)+\sinh(x))$. Maybe the problem was with $x$ playing a double role.

The idea simplifies the differentiation and evaluation at $x=\ln 2$, so is nice in that sense. But it has to be carried out correctly.

Comment: my try is : 32[cosh(x)*2cosh(2x)-sinh(2x)sinh(x) , is that correct ??

Comment: For differentiating as it stands, almost. But no minus sign, the derivative of $\cosh x$ is $\sinh x$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need all these identities? What about differentiating it as it is using the product rule and substituting the value of $x$?
I get 215 for the answer.

Comment: my try is : 32[cosh(x)*2cosh(2x)-sinh(2x)sinh(x)  , is that correct ??